# Relatively Prime Cases of the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, sums-of-squares, euclidean-algorithm

The Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity states that the set of the sum of two squares is closed under multiplication.
$$(u^2 + v^2)(A^2 + B^2) = (uA \pm vb)^2 + (vA \mp uB)^2$$
This is easy to verify as
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(uA + vb)^2 + (vA - uB)^2\\
& = (u^2A^2 + 2uAvB + v^2B^2) + (v^2A^2 -2vAuB + u^2b^2)\\
& = (u^2A^2 + v^2B^2 + v^2A^2 + u^2B^2) \\ 
& = (u^2 + v^2)(A^2 + B^2)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The plus and minus can be flipped in the result.

However, suppose the case where $u \bot v \land A \bot B$ (u and v are relatively prime and A and B are relatively prime). I am pretty sure this should imply that $(uA + vB) \bot (vA - uB)$. Provided that $(u^2 + v^2) \land (A^2 + B^2)$ are odd, so that the product must be odd. however I'm not so sure how to go about it.

I know that according to the extended Euclidean algorithm,

$$ ux_1 + vx_2 = 1$$ and
$$ Ax_3 + Bx_4 = 1$$

But I cant seem to get that to imply anything about the two quantities of $(uA + vB)$ and $(vA - uB)$. Are there some other tricks of the gcd to make this work?

**EDIT:**

This conjecture needs to narrow down its preconditions. The product $(u^2 + v^2)(A^2 + B^2) = (uA \pm vb)^2 + (vA \mp uB)^2$ must be odd. Also, because there are two ways this new number can be written as the sum of two squares, I still claim that at least one of these pairs will be squares of relatively prime numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not.  As a counterexample, consider $$(u,v) = (51,73), \quad (A,B) = (37,41),$$ both pairs of which are relatively prime.  Their sums of squares is $$u^2 + v^2 = 7930, \quad A^2 + B^2 = 3050,$$ and the product is $24186500$, which also happens to be $(uA + vB)^2 + (vA - uB)^2 = 4880^2 + 610^2$.  But $\gcd(4880, 610) = 610$.  There are smaller counterexamples but this one seemed interesting since in fact $4880 = 8 \cdot 610$.

---

I found another counterexample to satisfy all your additional criteria.  You require that the product $(u^2+v^2)(A^2+B^2)$ is odd, and at least one of the two ways this product can be written as the sum of two squares according to the formula will consist of a pair of relatively prime integers; however, $$(u,v) = (1,8), \quad (A,B) = (2, 29)$$ gives the product $$(u^2+v^2)(A^2+B^2) = 54925 = 234^2 + 13^2 = 230^2 + 45^2,$$ yet $$\gcd(234,13) = 13, \quad \gcd(230, 45) = 5.$$

Comment: This is definitely a counter example to my question. However, suppose you were to take the other form of the identity, in which you have 24185600 = 1106^2 + 4792^2. Now, 1106 and 4792 are surely not relatively prime. Their gcd is 2. However, suppose that the number expressed as the some of two squares must in fact be odd this time. Does this change the result?

Comment: But sorry for failing to see that I needed some more limitations when I originally asked.

Comment: @Nucl3ic It's rather unfair to ask a question, have it answered completely as originally stated, and then **change** the question and unaccept the original answer.

Comment: Yeah I get that! I can accept your answer as you did answer my original question. I'm just trying to figure this out... that is all.